# 'set' object has no attribute 'rename' error when using GroupBy function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I'm trying to calculate a weighted mean by area in Pandas and am getting the following error 'set' object has no attribute 'rename'. I'm not sure what it's telling me.

```
# read in raw census tract data from .zip and convert to geodataframe
svi = gpd.read_file(r"C:\NewMapsPlus\Map698\us-communities-fire\data\SVI2018_US.zip")
# read in cdps shapefile
cdps = gpd.read_file(r'C:\NewMapsPlus\Map698\us-communities-fire\notebooks\data\cdps.shp')

# define fields to intersect on
overall_svi_column = 'RPL_THEMES'
cpd_area_id_column = 'GEOID'

#  intersect using overlay() function. 
inter = gpd.overlay(cdps_ec, svi_ec)
inter['area'] = inter.area

# calculate weighted mean using a lambda and groupby function
wm = lambda x: np.average(x, weights=inter.loc[x.index, 'area']) 
f = ({'wm'}).rename(columns={'overall_svi_column': 'wm_svi'})
newdf = inter.groupby(cpd_area_id_column).agg(f)
newdf.columns = newdf.columns.droplevel()
```

Comment: "set" is a python type that is defined by "{}". So I would search in the line : `f = ({'wm'}).rename(columns={'overall_svi_column': 'wm_svi'})` where {'wm'} might be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks @ZosoLedZep. I got the calculation to work without renaming the field. I need to figure that part out. See below.

Comment: [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) is a method of the GeoDataFrame/DataFrame, so  you need to make sure you're calling the rename method of a dataframe, not a dictionary or set. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but it should look something like `inter = inter.rename(columns={'overall_svi_column': 'wm_svi'})`

Answer (score 0):

```
# calculate weighted mean using a lambda and groupby function
wm = lambda x: np.average(x, weights=inter.loc[x.index, 'area']) 
f = {overall_svi_column:{wm}}
newdf = inter.groupby(cpd_area_id_column).agg(f)
newdf.columns = newdf.columns.droplevel()
```